# adding menu options to secondary menu links in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

im trying to add a menu option to the secondary menu navigation bar that can be found on the course pages, i can't find any reference to secondary men or the menu names in the root directory can anyone point me in the right direction ?

[secondary menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE35l.png)

[secondary-menu2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxjV2.png)

Moodle: version 4.0.1
theme : boost

p.s is there some sort of developer documentation to find where all these mustache file link to so its easier to find files

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API#Course_settings):

> Any plugin implementing the following callback in lib.php can extend
> the course settings navigation.
>
> ```
> function <component>_extend_navigation_course(navigation_node $parentnode, stdClass $course, context_course $context)
> ```

For example, for a plugin called `local_example`:

```
function local_example_extend_navigation_course(navigation_node $parentnode, stdClass $course, context_course $context) {
    $parentnode->add(
        "Display text",
        new moodle_url('/index.php'),
        navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING,
        null,
        "local_example_item",
        new pix_icon('i/courseevent', '')
    );
```

By default in the Boost theme for Moodle 4.0+, this will add a new item to the "More" overflow menu. You'll have to customise the theme if you want to change this behaviour